# Wrong arguments to DictWriter()

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write JSON to a csv:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        print 'output:', output_file
        output = csv.DictWriter(output_file, order_fields = sorted(fieldnames), restval = '')
        output.writeheader()
        output.writerow()
```

Get this error:

```
  File "process_json.py", line 16, in main
    output = csv.DictWriter(output_file, order_fields = sorted(fieldnames), restval = '')
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

What arguments should I be passing if not these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [signature of `DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)
```

You will see you forgot to pass the `fieldnames` argument. Indeed, you pass 3 arguments (including `self` because it is a class), but you forgot this second one, which is mandatory.
I think it is not `order_fields` but `fieldnames` you meant, so you don't need to set it as a positional argument:

```
output = csv.DictWriter(output_file, sorted(fieldnames), restval = '')
```